# How to select all posts in Wordpress that belong to a parent category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am managing a store that uses the WooCommerce plugin on Wordpress.

Their categories are configured as follows:

Cat 1
- Cat 1A
-- Cat 1B
--- Cat 1C

Cat 2
- Cat 2A
-- Cat 2B
--- Cat 2C

As you can see, the categories are nested.

The products (posts) belong to the bottom level of the category hierarchy.

What I would like is a select query which returns all products that fall under 'Cat 2' for example.

How can this be done?

Thank you,
Craig

Comment: Even though there may be a standard table schema for Wordpress, you should still post it here to make your question complete.

Answer (score 2):

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post', 
      'orderby' => 'ID', 
     /* 'meta_key' => 'rankk', */
      'order' => 'DESC', 
      'posts_per_page' => 100,
      'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => 'YOUR PARENT CATEGORY ID',
            ),
        ),
);

$q = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

// put post_type and parent category ID(Cat2) then this code will give what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jasbir.
Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I want to be able to select this in an SQL query.

I need to be able to update the prices of products within this parent category, of which there are 1000's!!

Comment: @cs10 Use the query and echo `$q->request` to get the sql

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I need in an SQL statement.

Just in case this might help anyone, here is the select query.

You need to find the term_taxonomy_id of the category that you wish to search for, in my case, Cat 2 has the ID of 8412.

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value, wp_term_relationships.object_id, wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
from wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_postmeta.post_id=wp_term_relationships.object_id
where term_taxonomy_id = '8412'
```